# How to run K6 through docker with influxdb and Grafana

Tags: javascript, docker, docker-compose, k6

I am trying to execute my k6 tests with docker-compose and then visualise the results in grafana. I have started my containers and then tried editing the command given in the documentation:

```
docker-compose run -v     \$PWD/samples:/scripts \k6 run     /scripts/es6sample.js
```

but I keep receiving errors and I am struggling to understand the pattern needed for the command. I want to run the test.js file in the screenshot below: [Repo format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAMSK.png)

The error I am receiving is:

```
ERROR: for k6_k6_run  Cannot create container for service k6: invalid volume specification: '/Documents/practice_k6/k6/tests:tests:rw': invalid mount config for type "bind": invalid mount path: 'tests' mount path must be absolute

ERROR: for k6  Cannot create container for service k6: invalid volume specification: '/Documents/practice_k6/k6/tests:tests:rw': invalid mount config for type "bind": invalid mount path: 'tests' mount path must be absolute
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
Eoins-MacBook-Air:k6 eoincorr$
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested I found the issue, it was in the volumes within docker-compose.yml file. The volumes in K6 had been entered incorrectly `tests:tests`   instead of `tests:/tests`

Answer (score 0):

One Could refer to the document i have created [here](https://community.k6.io/t/preload-grafana-dashbaord-with-docker-compose-setup/874) for using the docker-compose setup.